# How do I get babel to output ES2016

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a React project currently running through webpack and babel to transpile and bundle the code which includes JSX. The code is transpiled to ES5, but I would like to output ES2016. How can I transform the JSX and output ES2016?

Comment: What presets are you currently using?

Comment: currenty using "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]

Comment: Would removing the es2016 preset not accomplish what you're seeking?

Comment: Ok, so removing the "es2015" preset has prevented the modules from working. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import". I can't see a plugin for ES2015 style modules on the babel docs. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question... Try this preset: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2016/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but es2016 preset didn't load es2015 style modules. I've now found a solution with a module plugin. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

{
  "presets": ["react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}

This babel.rc config works by transforming the ES2015 modules into CommonJS which webpack can then deal with.